# Ruby - How do you access the key value in parsed json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, parsing

I am getting this json as a response to my api call. I need to get the comment to verify it in my test. I would get only one record in the response. How can I access the comment value "Italian Recipes."?
I did JSON.parse(response) and got the ruby hash. I need help in extracting the value from the hash.

```
{  
   “recipe”:{  
      "id":10,
      "created_at":"2019-03-16T22:21:03Z",
      "updated_at":"2019-03-16T23:07:07Z",
        },
   "audit":{  
      "id":402216837440,
      "recipe_id":10,
      "created_at":"2019-03-16T23:07:07Z",
       "events":[  
         {  
            "id":402216837460,
            "author_id":179,
            "Comment":"Italian Recipes.",
            "audit_id":402216837440
         }
      ],
      "via":{  
         "channel":"api"
         }
   }
}
```

I tried this but I think this is not the correct format. I am getting error. Need help with the correct syntax.

```
parsed_response = JSON.parse(res)
parsed_response['audit']['events']['comment']
```

Comment: Hint: Feeding this to `JSON.parse` will give you a ruby hash.

Comment: "but I think this is not the correct format" - well, of course. `events` is an array. In this case it contains only one element, but if it contained several, which comment would you like to get?

Comment: if `"json"` is your string, you know that the immediate key is `"Comment"`, and that key appears no where else (even if you don't know the remaining structure rest of the hash) you could write `json[/(?<=\"Comment":")[\p{Alnum}, ]+/] #=> "Italian Recipes"`. If you do know the structure of the hash, however, you really  should convert the string to a hash and dig for the value you want. Note that double and single quotes have no special meaning in regular expressions.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the answer you selected, but in future please consider waiting longer before making a selection. Quick selections can discourage other answers and some believe they are discourteous to those still working on answers. The point is that there is no rush. Most askers wait at least a couple of hours, some much longer than that.

Comment: Noted! I am a newbie and I accepted the answer because it worked for me. I will wait in the future

Comment: I just happened to see your comment. To have members notified of comments left for them include their user name (or part of it ) in the comment, preceded by an ampersan (e.g., @Cary).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: that's not an ampersand, though :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland got it :)

Comment: @Sergio, I made that mistake before. It might have been you who corrected me previously. Let's see if I remember in future.

Comment: @Cary: I'll be watching you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
json_data = JSON.parse(json_string)
comment = json_data['audit']['events'].first['Comment']
recipe_id = json_data['recipe']['id']
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. could you please help me access the id in the recipe? I tried json_data['recipe'].first['id'] and I got the error undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass. This works in cases where there are more records. I get this error only when there is only one record

Comment: @stuart: from what you show us, recipe is not an array, why are you using `first` on it? (but it also shouldn't raise this error. Are you sure your `json_data` has the key `recipe`?)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes my json_data has recipe key

Comment: @stuart I've updated the answer to get the recipe_id as well.